# How to get the last array value inside foreach in php?

Tags: php, foreach

I am having code as,

```
    $totals = [];

    foreach ($student_due_fee as $key => $fee) {
    foreach ($fee->fees as $fee_key => $fee_value) {

    $group_id = $fee_value->fee_groups_id;

    if(!isset($totals[$group_id])){

       $totals[$group_id] = $fee_value->amount;
       }else{

       $totals[$group_id] += $fee_value->amount;
       print_r($totals);
     }
   }
  }
```

And the output is,

```
Array ( [69] => 3000 ) 
Array ( [69] => 6000 ) 
Array ( [69] => 6000 [70] => 3500 ) 
Array ( [69] => 6000 [70] => 4500 )
```

Here i need to get the last value as end result which is,

```
Array ( [69] => 6000 [70] => 4500 )
```

How can i get the last array value without moving out of foreach loop?

Image of the result,

[image]

Here i am doing the sum of amount based on group and storing it to $totals inside foreach  and i need to display the final result that comes while doing `print_r($totals)`  which is     `Array ( [69] => 6000 [70] => 4500 )` .

Output of $fee->fees is,

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 19 [student_session_id] => 278 [fee_session_group_id] => 15 [is_active] => no [created_at] => 2018-04-17 05:18:41 [fee_groups_feetype_id] => 74 [amount] => 1000.00 [due_date] => 2018-04-24 [fee_groups_id] => 69 [name] => Ist Term - LKG [feetype_id] => 1 [code] => ISEMTUTION [type] => I SEM TUTION FEES [student_fees_deposite_id] => 0 [amount_detail] => 0 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 19 [student_session_id] => 278 [fee_session_group_id] => 15 [is_active] => no [created_at] => 2018-04-17 05:18:41 [fee_groups_feetype_id] => 75 [amount] => 2000.00 [due_date] => 2018-04-24 [fee_groups_id] => 69 [name] => Ist Term - LKG [feetype_id] => 2 [code] => IITUTION [type] => II SEM TUTION FEES [student_fees_deposite_id] => 0 [amount_detail] => 0 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 19 [student_session_id] => 278 [fee_session_group_id] => 15 [is_active] => no [created_at] => 2018-04-17 05:18:41 [fee_groups_feetype_id] => 76 [amount] => 3000.00 [due_date] => 2018-04-24 [fee_groups_id] => 69 [name] => Ist Term - LKG [feetype_id] => 3 [code] => SPORTS [type] => SPORTS FEES [student_fees_deposite_id] => 0 [amount_detail] => 0 ) ) 

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 65 [student_session_id] => 278 [fee_session_group_id] => 16 [is_active] => no [created_at] => 2018-04-17 05:20:20 [fee_groups_feetype_id] => 77 [amount] => 2000.00 [due_date] => 2018-04-24 [fee_groups_id] => 70 [name] => IInd Term - LKG [feetype_id] => 7 [code] => MAGAZINE [type] => MAGAZINE, PHOTOS,BAG, ID etc [student_fees_deposite_id] => 0 [amount_detail] => 0 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 65 [student_session_id] => 278 [fee_session_group_id] => 16 [is_active] => no [created_at] => 2018-04-17 05:20:20 [fee_groups_feetype_id] => 78 [amount] => 1500.00 [due_date] => 2018-04-24 [fee_groups_id] => 70 [name] => IInd Term - LKG [feetype_id] => 8 [code] => SCHOLASTICS [type] => CO - SCHOLASTICS [student_fees_deposite_id] => 0 [amount_detail] => 0 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 65 [student_session_id] => 278 [fee_session_group_id] => 16 [is_active] => no [created_at] => 2018-04-17 05:20:20 [fee_groups_feetype_id] => 79 [amount] => 1000.00 [due_date] => 2018-04-24 [fee_groups_id] => 70 [name] => IInd Term - LKG [feetype_id] => 9 [code] => BOOKSUNIFORM [type] => BOOKS, NOTEBOOKS, UNIFORM [student_fees_deposite_id] => 0 [amount_detail] => 0 ) )
```

And output of $fee_value is,

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 19 [student_session_id] => 278 [fee_session_group_id] => 15 [is_active] => no [created_at] => 2018-04-17 05:18:41 [fee_groups_feetype_id] => 74 [amount] => 1000.00 [due_date] => 2018-04-24 [fee_groups_id] => 69 [name] => Ist Term - LKG [feetype_id] => 1 [code] => ISEMTUTION [type] => I SEM TUTION FEES [student_fees_deposite_id] => 0 [amount_detail] => 0 ) 

stdClass Object ( [id] => 19 [student_session_id] => 278 [fee_session_group_id] => 15 [is_active] => no [created_at] => 2018-04-17 05:18:41 [fee_groups_feetype_id] => 75 [amount] => 2000.00 [due_date] => 2018-04-24 [fee_groups_id] => 69 [name] => Ist Term - LKG [feetype_id] => 2 [code] => IITUTION [type] => II SEM TUTION FEES [student_fees_deposite_id] => 0 [amount_detail] => 0 ) 

stdClass Object ( [id] => 19 [student_session_id] => 278 [fee_session_group_id] => 15 [is_active] => no [created_at] => 2018-04-17 05:18:41 [fee_groups_feetype_id] => 76 [amount] => 3000.00 [due_date] => 2018-04-24 [fee_groups_id] => 69 [name] => Ist Term - LKG [feetype_id] => 3 [code] => SPORTS [type] => SPORTS FEES [student_fees_deposite_id] => 0 [amount_detail] => 0 ) 

stdClass Object ( [id] => 65 [student_session_id] => 278 [fee_session_group_id] => 16 [is_active] => no [created_at] => 2018-04-17 05:20:20 [fee_groups_feetype_id] => 77 [amount] => 2000.00 [due_date] => 2018-04-24 [fee_groups_id] => 70 [name] => IInd Term - LKG [feetype_id] => 7 [code] => MAGAZINE [type] => MAGAZINE, PHOTOS,BAG, ID etc [student_fees_deposite_id] => 0 [amount_detail] => 0 ) 

stdClass Object ( [id] => 65 [student_session_id] => 278 [fee_session_group_id] => 16 [is_active] => no [created_at] => 2018-04-17 05:20:20 [fee_groups_feetype_id] => 78 [amount] => 1500.00 [due_date] => 2018-04-24 [fee_groups_id] => 70 [name] => IInd Term - LKG [feetype_id] => 8 [code] => SCHOLASTICS [type] => CO - SCHOLASTICS [student_fees_deposite_id] => 0 [amount_detail] => 0 ) 

stdClass Object ( [id] => 65 [student_session_id] => 278 [fee_session_group_id] => 16 [is_active] => no [created_at] => 2018-04-17 05:20:20 [fee_groups_feetype_id] => 79 [amount] => 1000.00 [due_date] => 2018-04-24 [fee_groups_id] => 70 [name] => IInd Term - LKG [feetype_id] => 9 [code] => BOOKSUNIFORM [type] => BOOKS, NOTEBOOKS, UNIFORM [student_fees_deposite_id] => 0 [amount_detail] => 0 )
```

Comment: uh, what made you shy away from checking the array size then get the last index?

Comment: `echo end($fee->fees)` or in this case, it should be var_dump or something like it since it's an array. `$last = end($fee->fees)`

Comment: that's very primitive

Comment: to add to the above, http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php documents it

Comment: @Wils can you clarify what you mean? What is you think is "primitive", exactly?

Comment: If you are shying away from utilizing predefined PHP core functions and instead want to over-engineer solutions, maybe try c++.

Comment: re your latest edit. For that, simply move `print_r($totals);` after the end of the loop. Then it will only print the last version of the array. Right now you print multiple versions of the array, one after each change to it. Before you were asking for the "last item in the array" which is simply `4500` - that's what all the answers are trying to give you

Comment: @ADyson, But i need that last one inside the foreach loop, is it possible? Because i need to get the fee type based on the group total. If the total is ```6000``` the it comes from ```1000+2000+3000``` in which each one is a fee type and i need to get the fee type so inside foreach i need to do it..

Comment: @ADyson, If i am wrong then help me how to display the total of each group and while submit i have to send all the types inside the group..

Comment: To make it handy, can you provide a sample object? $fee->fees

Comment: @ManiRaj I have no idea what you mean, then. " that last one inside the foreach loop" ..what exactly do you want, if not the thing you've explicitly asked for??? You asked how to print only the last version of the array, I showed you. If that isn't what you mean, then you need to give a much better explanation. Right now it's as clear as mud.

Comment: @ADyson, I said in question that i how to make output without going out of foreach.. Because i am having types inside that foreach, if i get out of the loop i wont get the fee types..

Comment: @ADyson don't let him get to you. Just take a deep breath and click the downvote, and breath out. You will feel much better. I just tried it myself.

Comment: I don't get why doing the output inside inside the foreach is important to you - you're printing the whole array, so if you print it _inside_ the foreach, you'll see it every time the loop runs. But then you said you only want to see it once, the final version. To do that you have to move that print_r outside the loop. And I don't understand how the screenshot is in any way related to the code or your question. You might be better to delete your question, think it all through again, and start a new one which actually provides clear info.

Comment: I have voted to close this as unclear, as it seems everyone who is viewing it is confused. Even Manj seems confused!

Comment: @ADyson the screenshot is almost the same as the input array, but not even close.

Comment: @Andreas as far as I'm aware we've never been given the input array? And the question states that this table is the output, but is entirely unrelated to the output being generated by the code sample.

Comment: @ADyson oh.. so the image is the output. The print_r output or another output also completely irrelevant to the question. Gosh... If there was only an input... Where is the "Vote to hall of fame" button?

Comment: @Andreas True. If only OP could explain themselves properly as well. The later comments above appear to introduce some other things such as "fee type" which are nowhere to be seen in any of the code and make no sense at all. And the request "show last version of the array" and "do it in the foreach" are entirely contradictory and nonsensical. The whole thing is a mess, in a way the original version made very slightly more sense, although clearly it wasn't what he actually wanted (whatever that might be). I sometimes wish it was possible to downvote multiple times...

Comment: @Mani Raj, if you need to get your expected solution, the sample of input is needed. foreach loop is just a function for repeated procedure, unless a specific condition is set, it will just loop till the end of array. So, share your object, so we can help to set a condition to print your needed output

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen, May be by mistake i have added many things into my question and it got messes up. I hope you will understand what i am exactly in the need of, I have updated my question with whats coming from $fee->fees..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Based on your edited post with additional foreach loop**:

If you need the output in your last foreach loop, you will first need to know the count of $student_due_fee and compare with a counter:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [fees] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [fee_groups_id] => 69
                            [amount] => 1000
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [fee_groups_id] => 69
                            [amount] => 2000
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [fee_groups_id] => 70
                            [amount] => 1000
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [fees] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [fee_groups_id] => 69
                            [amount] => 3000
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [fee_groups_id] => 70
                            [amount] => 2000
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [fee_groups_id] => 70
                            [amount] => 1500
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Count your object

```
$count = count((array)$student_due_fee);
```

Start your $counter from 0

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ($student_due_fee as $fee) {
    foreach ($fee->fees as $fee_value) {

        $group_id = $fee_value->fee_groups_id;

        if(!isset($totals[$group_id])){

            $totals[$group_id] = $fee_value->amount;
        }   else    {

            $totals[$group_id] += $fee_value->amount;
        }
    }
    $counter++;
    if ($counter == $count) {
        echo "\r\n";
        print_r($totals);
    }    
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [69] => 6000
    [70] => 4500
)
```

[fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9481a5c7b736a563dec240100ad970a95f57ed16)

Comment: For me its showing as, 
```Array ( [69] => 6000 ) 
Array ( [69] => 6000 [70] => 4500 )``` , I have tried what you said but there was extra  Array ( [69] => 6000 )  in first row..

Comment: Are you having a nested foreach?

Comment: Sorry for not adding that, yes i am having nested foreach, and i am new in PHP so kindly regret and help me.. Updated question with nested foreach..

Comment: All I can say is check your implementation. I have already provided a sample object and a fiddle.

Comment: Yes your sample is much more clear and thanks for your help once again..

Comment: @ManiRaj, please accept the answer or I consider my answer doesn't help and this answer will be removed. To be honest, I feel bad helping. You can see the frustration from others who had help.

Answer (score 2):

Why not

```
end($fee->fees)
```

That'll give you the last item in your array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use php default array function called `end()` like this

```
<?php
   $people = array("Peter", "Joe", "Glenn", "Cleveland");
   echo end($people); 
?>
```

output of the above code is :

```
Cleveland
```

here is  the link where you can checkout this thing [[here]](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_end.asp)

as suggested by Andreas wwe can use `array_slice()` as well for doing the same in different way.

Comment: I am in the need of output like,  ```Array ( [69] => 6000 [70] => 4500 ) ``` inside the foreach loop.

Comment: you can still use the same function inside the loop.. correct me if i misunderstood anything @ManiRaj

Comment: @ManiRaj for that you can use print_r instead of echo, if you require that exact output

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`end()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php)

code example would be

```
$test = array('test1', 'test2', 'test3');

echo end($test);
```

output would be *test3*

Comment: Ok but why are you telling us here?

Comment: sorry it was cut of for somme reason >-<

Comment: Ok well if you're going to suggest something then that's perfectly fine as an answer (although you should include a code example within the question, not just a link)...but then again the exact same answer was posted several minutes earlier.

Comment: when i originally  did write the answer it was not yet posted... sorry

Comment: Well that's fair enough I guess. But you should edit it to remove the fluff about not being able to comment (it's irrelevant, and anyway this is an ok answer), include a code snippet directly, and edit so that the link description is meaningful. An explanation is always good as well, so people understand your reasoning. Kishan's answer above is a decent model to emulate.

Comment: or should i just delete my post ?

Comment: No, I think now it's perfectly reasonable.

Comment: thank you very much for you're help. It was not my intent to post a bad post.

Comment: Don't post the same answer again and again.. try to learn from Andreas he use array_slice to do the same ..keep SO clean :)

Comment: @KishanOza read the comments above and look at the timestamps before ranting. This answer was originally posted at almost the same time as the very first answer given, and certainly several minutes before yours. nothing wrong with that. Some of the answers here are very similar, probably because the answer is quite simple and straightforward, but it appears this was not trying to spam a duplicate answer, it was a genuine attempt. It's merely the edits which are more recent - I was trying to help a new user structure their post well. I used yours as an example of a good one - take a compliment!

Comment: ohh yaah but when I was writing my question I didn't see this answer so thats why get confused :)

Answer (score 1):

As I posted in comments, and as others has posted in answers end works good.
But I like to use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) over end since you can specify how many items you want.

```
$arr = array(array ( 69 => 3000 ),
array ( 69 => 6000 ),
array ( 69 => 6000, 70 => 3500 ),
array ( 69 => 6000, 70 => 4500 ));

var_dump(array_slice($arr, -1)); // last item
echo "\n\n";
var_dump(array_slice($arr, -2)); // last two items
```

A negative number in array_slice means it counts from end n number of items.

https://3v4l.org/L4Niu

---

EDIT:

```
$totals = [];

foreach ($fee->fees as $fee_key => $fee_value) {

$group_id = $fee_value->fee_groups_id;

if(!isset($totals[$group_id])){

   $totals[$group_id] = $fee_value->amount;
   }else{

   $totals[$group_id] += $fee_value->amount;

 }

}
print_r($totals);
//var_dump(array_slice($fee->fees, -1));
```

as mentioned in comments below $totals is an array, so printing it after the loop should give you the expected output.

Comment: why to use such messy code when u have function called `end()` :D

Comment: @KishanOza In what way is it more messy? it's either end or array_slice? It's still only one function.

Comment: yaah right but when u just want the last element why go such far ?? :) just kidding bro you are also right :)

Comment: @Andreas, When i use your code, it is showing ```array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "1000.00" } array(1) { [0]=> float(3000) } array(1) { [0]=> float(6000) } array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "2000.00" } array(1) { [0]=> float(3500) } array(1) { [0]=> float(4500) }```

Comment: @KishanOza I usually don't like to reinvent the wheel each time i code. I generally try to use functions that can be used to many applications not just one. End only works for the last item. Array_slice works in many more situations. And to top it off, your code does not works since you try to echo an array

Comment: yaah true @Andreas array_slice works in many more situations. at the end we both are right at our own ways :)

Comment: @Andreas, ```                    if(!isset($totals[$group_id])){
                      $totals[$group_id] = $fee_value->amount;
                    }else{
                      $totals[$group_id] += $fee_value->amount;
                      var_dump(array_slice($totals, -1));
                    }```

Comment: @ManiRaj If that is the code, nothing in it shows why you get the problem. But I assume you have the var_dump inside the loop? Move it outside the loop.

Comment: Thats what i said in question, without moving outside of the loop i need to get the value.

Comment: @ManiRaj See my edit above. You need to var_dump the $fee->fees  last item not the variable used in the loop.

Comment: @Andreas The print_r($totals) gives the output i mentioned in the question, in which i need to get the last array value.. Is it possible inside the foreach loop to get the last value of the $totals variable?

Comment: @ManiRaj Is $totals an array? It's hard to follow your code when we don't see the input only the output.

Comment: @Andreas, Yes $totals is an array, each time it comes into the loop and making addition of values in which i need to get the last value which i mentioned in the question.

Comment: @ManiRaj See my edit above, I think you need to move the print to after the loop.'

Comment: @ManiRaj `var_dump(array_slice($totals, -1));` then? It would be a lot easier if you give us a sample of the $fees data you are using.

Comment: @ADyson If $totals is an array with the output posted in the question it should only have the two items as in question. The reson he get it multiple times is because he outputs it in the loop and it's adding the values on each iteration.

Comment: @Andreas yes...so if it has two items, he still wants only the last one. So a simple print_r will print both items

Comment: @ADyson That is how I understand it. EDIT, no. I think he want's both items. Or... So confusing to not get proper input and output in question.

Comment: @ManiRaj see my comment on the main question, above. You have, until now, been asking for two contradictory things, which may explain Andreas' confusion (and mine). Since your edit, the answer is very simple and merely a matter of changing where you place your print_r statement. Either you got your terminology confused or you don't understand that your code was printing multiple versions of the same thing

Comment: @ManiRaj just try my latest code revision. If that is not it I don't think anyone can ever help you. And for future, you need to work on your question typing.

Comment: @Andreas, Sorry for the inconvenience and i will focus on asking clear thing hereafter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `count()` function to get the number of array values in your case '4'.

```
$arrCount = count($array); # will equal 4 for OP
$arrCount = $arrCount - 1;
echo $array[$arrCount]; # last value in the array
```

Comment: I see other answers have done this with less code, learning from my side too :)